# AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly / AWS cognito, React JS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am facing this issue. After installing amplify-cli, aws-amplify and aws-amplify-react, not able to use aws cognito. My code snippet is given below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import config from './aws-exports';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <b>Hello World..</b>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, {includeGreetings: true});
```

I have added
amplify add auth
amplify push

But constantly getting this issue.

Error image attached below.. please have a look
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue after a lot of research. The problem is solved by installing @aws-amplify/core package in the react js application by using the following command.

```
npm i @aws-amplify/core --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

But after installing that in my case, I received error as this package was showing a lot of dependency packages. So after finally adding all those as mentioned below, the cognito aws login/signup problem got solved..

```
npm i @aws-amplify/storage --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/interactions --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/auth --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/api --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/analytics --save --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @aws-amplify/xr --save --legacy-peer-deps
```